# Array to property Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help please.

I have this array in php:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [name] => Ville1 
        [description] => adresse1 
        [lng] => -10.35 
        [lat] => 29.1833 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => Ville2 
        [description] => description2 
        [lng] => 12.61667 
        [lat] => 38.3833 
    ) 
)
```

How can I transform it in this format and add in a objet in javascript ?

```
locations: {
    "0": {
      lat: "48.3833",
      lng: "12.61667",
      name: "Ville1",
      description: "adresse1"
    },
    "1": {
      lat: "29.1833",
      lng: "-10.35",
      name: "Ville2",
      description: "adresse2"
    }
  },
```

Thanks and sorry for the english..

Comment: Use `json_encode()` function.

Comment: Just use json_encode() , it will convert your array to JSON formatted string.

Comment: Yes I have use this in php file:   let json = <?php echo json_encode($depots); ?>; but after ? ($depot is my array) I have do myObjet.location = json; but it doesn't work because the format is not good, how to write 1,2 like exemple ?

Comment: Use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag to make the result an object with numeric keys instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your PHP Code accordingly. It should be working for you.

```
$array = [
    [
        "name" => "Ville1",
        "description" => "adresse1",
        "lng" => -10.35,
        "lat" => 29.1833
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Ville2",
        "description" => "description2",
        "lng" => 12.61667,
        "lat" => 38.3833
    ]
];
foreach ($array as $keys => $value ) {
    $object->{$keys} = $value;
}
$jsonStructure = json_encode($object); 
echo $jsonStructure;
```

The output should be like this :

```
{
  "0": {
    "name": "Ville1",
    "description": "adresse1",
    "lng": -10.35,
    "lat": 29.1833
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "Ville2",
    "description": "description2",
    "lng": 12.61667,
    "lat": 38.3833
  }
}
```

Now you can use this `$jsonStructure` to your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. The only think you have to do, is to pass the array to the php function `json_encode`.

This will convert automatically your array to JSON.

The same way, you could also convert PHP Objects to JSON.

Finally, there's also another function of PHP with the name `json_decode` that does the opposite. If you have a JSON string, you can convert it to PHP Array or Object.

The only difference, is that when you convert JSON objects, in PHP you get `stdClass` instances.

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [
        "name" => "Ville1",
        "description" => "adresse1",
        "lng" => -10.35,
        "lat" => 29.1833
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Ville2",
        "description" => "description2",
        "lng" => 12.61667,
        "lat" => 38.3833
    ]
];

$jsonStructure = json_encode($array);

?>
<script>
var locations = <?php echo $jsonStructure; ?>;

// The following line should print in your browser console 
// the word: Ville1
console.log(locations[0].name);
</script>
```

Comment: @DarkBee what you mean? How to access the produced JSON from JavaScript? I am not sure this is what he ask. Let me see his question again :)

Comment: @DarkBee you may be right.

Comment: You should use a forereach to get the actual output as expected.

foreach ($array as $keys => $value ) {
    $object->{$keys} = $value;
}

I have added an answer, you can check :)